# Question about ending of Assassins Creed 4: Black Flag

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

This is the first Assassins Creed game I have played. Obviously the question includes spoilers:

> In the final scene that takes place in present day, John (the IT guy) express his anger and disappointment that you were not possessed by Juno. I gather that Jon is a reincarnation of Bartholomew Roberts, and he seems ready to kill you out of anger with a syringe of something foul. It turns out however, that the shot John gives you was far below the lethal dosage.

Question:

> **What was the point of the syringe if John did not intend to kill you?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John is a [Sage](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Sages), a reincarnation of Junos Husband Aita. 
And well, he did intented to kill "you". 
He was just interrupted by the Abstergo Security Team when they came into the room by force after they discovered what John had been doing. And by luck the already injected dose was below lethal-levels

You can check John's Wiki [here](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/John_Standish) but you won't understand much if AC: Black Flag was your first AC game. I recommend you play all of them to truly understand what's going on. If you don't have time you can always read up on the wiki and find info there :)

Comment: Thanks. So it is the old troupe of the villain taking to long to explain his point of view before he kills you. Very James Bond-like.